# How do I define a unique property for a Model in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need some properties to be unique. How can I achieve this?

Is there something like `unique=True`?

I'm using Google App Engine for Python.

Comment: Blixt, editing to make the title say app engine is good since many app engine questions are language agnostic, but somewhere the question should mention that the poster is interested in a python answer not a java one.

Comment: You're right. I considered adding it before as well, but figured that a Java solution would point the OP in the right direction as well. But I suppose that the Java and Python versions of GAE are different enough to make this question Python-specific.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no built-in constraint for making sure a value is unique. You can do this however:

```
query = MyModel.all(keys_only=True).filter('unique_property', value_to_be_used)
entity = query.get()
if entity:
    raise Exception('unique_property must have a unique value!')
```

I use `keys_only=True` because it'll improve the performance slightly by not fetching the data for the entity.

A more efficient method would be to use a separate model with no fields whose key name is made up of property name + value. Then you could use `get_by_key_name` to fetch one or more of these composite key names and if you get one or more not-`None` values, you know there are duplicate values (and checking which values were not `None`, you'll know which ones were not unique.)

---

As *onebyone* mentioned in the comments, these approaches – by their get first, put later nature – run the risk concurrency issues. Theoretically, an entity could be created just after the check for an existing value, and then the code after the check will still execute, leading to duplicate values. To prevent this, you will have to use transactions: [Transactions - Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html)

---

If you're looking to check for uniqueness across *all* entities with transactions, you'd have to put all of them in the same group using the first method, which would be very inefficient. For transactions, use the second method like this:

```
class UniqueConstraint(db.Model):
    @classmethod
    def check(cls, model, **values):
        # Create a pseudo-key for use as an entity group.
        parent = db.Key.from_path(model.kind(), 'unique-values')

        # Build a list of key names to test.
        key_names = []
        for key in values:
            key_names.append('%s:%s' % (key, values[key]))

        def txn():
            result = cls.get_by_key_name(key_names, parent)
            for test in result:
                if test: return False
            for key_name in key_names:
                uc = cls(key_name=key_name, parent=parent)
                uc.put()
            return True

        return db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

`UniqueConstraint.check(...)` will assume that every single key/value pair must be unique to return success. The transaction will use a single entity group for every model kind. This way, the transaction is reliable for several different fields at once (for only one field, this would be much simpler.) Also, even if you've got fields with the same name in one or more models, they will not conflict with each other.

Comment: It's possible to put these in transactions, but I'll leave that to the OP.

Comment: @onebyone: I updated my post with code to show what I meant with the second method. It does use very broad entity groups, but I would hope he's not doing more than five inserting `put`s per second per model.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that this one creates an entity group for each class, limiting the insertion speed at one per second? Would it introduce any inconsistency to make a hash of all the properties being checked and add it as a string to the 'unique-values', thus making multiple entity groups?

Comment: @petr If you do unique checks on completely different sets of properties on the same entity kind, then adding a hash would improve performance. **But**, if you have overlapping sets of properties, then you may run into inconsistencies, yes.

Comment: Ok, my idea is to use unique constraint to check for username uniqueness during registration. This could be quite a problem to limit signups to one per second, so I have added simple hashing [code](http://pastebin.com/TGRVtTNA). I cannot see how this could be a problem as same usernames should map to the same pseudo-key and thus maintain consistency. Am I doing something wrong? (conceptually)

Comment: @Blixt: I used second method, it works fine when we insert entity. I am calling UniqueConstraint.check() function during validation of form and will display validation error if values is not unique. In Edit form, validation fails when user tries to save the entity as there is key in UniqueConstraint kind. So, how can we handle such a problem. For more info, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441804/checking-uniqueness-contraint-during-form-validation-in-app-engine .

Comment: Links are dead. @Blixt can you update them or remove them?

Comment: @Max: Done. Unfortunately my example went down now that App Engine deprecated the old data store.

Answer (score 25):

Google has provided function to do that:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert

```
Model.get_or_insert(key_name, **kwds)
```

Attempts to get the entity of the model's kind with the given key name. If it exists, get_or_insert() simply returns it. If it doesn't exist, a new entity with the given kind, name, and parameters in kwds is created, stored, and returned.

The get and subsequent (possible) put are wrapped in a transaction to ensure atomicity. Ths means that get_or_insert() will never overwrite an existing entity, and will insert a new entity if and only if no entity with the given kind and name exists.

In other words, get_or_insert() is equivalent to this Python code:

```
def txn():
  entity = MyModel.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=kwds.get('parent'))
  if entity is None:
    entity = MyModel(key_name=key_name, **kwds)
    entity.put()
  return entity
return db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

**Arguments:**

key_name
  The name for the key of the entity
**kwds
  Keyword arguments to pass to the model class's constructor if an instance with the specified key name doesn't exist. The parent argument is required if the desired entity has a parent.

**Note: get_or_insert() does not accept an RPC object.**

The method returns an instance of the model class that represents the requested entity, whether it existed or was created by the method. As with all datastore operations, this method can raise a TransactionFailedError if the transaction could not be completed.