# How to overwrite the put() method on a python app engine model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In Appengine, I am trying to have a property value computed automatically and stored with the object.

I have a class, Rectangle, and it has a width, height and area. Obviously the area is a function of width and height, but I want it to be a property because I want to use it for sorting. So I try to modify the put() function to sneak the area in when storing the Rectangle like so:

```
class Rectangle(db.Model):
    width   = db.IntegerProperty()
    height  = db.IntegerProperty()
    area    = db.IntegerProperty()

    def put(self, **kwargs):
        self.area = self.width * self.height
        super(Rectangle, self).put(**kwargs)
```

This works when I invoke `put()` on the Area object directly:

```
re1 = Rectangle(width=10, height=10)
re1.put()
print re1.area      # >> 10
```

But when I use `db.put()` (e.g. to save a lot of them at once), this breaks.

```
re2 = Rectangle(width=5, height=5)
db.put(re2)
print re2.area      # >> None
```

What is the proper way to 'sneak in' the computed value?

Comment: what do you get if you fetch the item from the database ? is the area calculated ?

Comment: I checked the datastore and it says the same; `10` for the first rectangle and `None` for the second.

Comment: I suspect that `db.put()` never calls the individual `put()` method on your objects -- it probably inspects them for database properties and creates bulk insert statements.  If you set area in `__init__` instead of in `put`, what happens?

Comment: I am not inclined to overwrite `__init__`. It is bad practice, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279833/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't override put - as you observe, it's fragile, and doesn't get invoked if you call `db.put` instead of the model's put function.

Fortunately, App Engine provides a `ComputedProperty` which makes your use-case really easy:

```
class Rectangle(db.Model):
    width   = db.IntegerProperty()
    height  = db.IntegerProperty()

    @db.ComputedProperty
    def area(self):
      return self.width * self.height
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `ComputedProperty` is the way to go for the specific scenario described. However,  it could still be useful to overload the `put` function.  For instance, we employ the following code to keep track of all of the callers who are issuing datastore writes so that we can easily debug spikes in writes.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

_orig_db_put_async = db.put_async
_orig_db_model_put = db.Model.put

def _new_db_put_async(models, *args, **kwargs):
    """Instrumented version of db.put_async (which db.put also calls)."""
    retval = _orig_db_put_async(models, *args, **kwargs)
    msg = ['query: %s' % _get_caller()]
    # 'models' can be either a single model instance, or a list of them.
    try:
        for model in models:
            msg.append(model.__class__.__name__ + '.<db.put>')
    except TypeError:
        msg.append(models.__class__.__name__ + '.<db.put>')
    instance_cache.increment(' -- '.join(msg))
    return retval


def _new_db_model_put(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Like entity.put() but stores put-stats in the instance cache."""
    retval = _orig_db_model_put(self, *args, **kwargs)
    msg = ['query: %s' % _get_caller()]
    msg.append(self.__class__.__name__ + '.<put>')
    instance_cache.increment(' -- '.join(msg))
    return retval
```

This code keeps a count of which codepaths are issuing writes in memcache and then occasionally flushes it out to the logs.  The log lines look something like this:

`3041: activity_summary.py:312 -- UserData.<put>`

Where `3041` is the number of times line `312` of activity_summary.py issued a `UserData.put()`.