# db.Model init override techniques?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, inheritance

I need to implement support for i18n of entity content. Before the refactoring the code looks like this:

```
class Project (db.Model)
    description = db.TextProperty()
```

I implement i18n using @property builtin, to avoid a refactoring of all the code getting  or setting the description property

```
class Project (db.Model)
    # English
    description_en = db.TextProperty()

    # Spanish
    description_es = db.TextProperty()

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self.description_es

    @description.setter
    def description(self, value):
        self.description_es = value
```

The problem came when I try to do this:

```
project = Project(description = "Foo bar")
```

I use that syntax to init models a lot in a large codebase, I can't refactor that. But the db.Model **init** only set db.properties no @properties.

I try to override the init method of db.Model but I got a lot of errors and it seems that [is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280270/78718).

My questions are:

Is there a way to safely override the init methods of `db.Model`?

Are there other ways to implement i18n of content that not imply large refactoring of my code?

Comment: You really can't refactor all your uses of the constructor of a single class? That seems odd, since it's not particularly difficult.

Comment: @nick-johnson I ended up doing that, the code that needed refactoring was mainly unit tests.