# Require an entity parent in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a model that is meaningless without a parent. Is there a way to force an entity to have a parent? I would like an exception to be raised if the child entity is ever instantiated without a parent, similar to a required property.

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    eye_color = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Child(db.Model):
    pass
```

Does not raise an exception:

```
mom = Parent(eye_color='purple')
jimmy = Child(parent=mom)
```

Raises an exception:

```
mom = Parent(eye_color='purple')
jimmy = Child()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this personally, but you should be able to override `__init__` for the Child class and check to make sure the parent is not None.  Like so:

```
class Child(db.Model):
  pass

  def __init__(self,
               parent=None,
               key_name=None,
               _app=None,
               _from_entity=False,
               **kwds):
    if not parent:
      raise ValueError('parent is required.')
    super(Did, self).__init__(parent=parent, key_name=key_name, app=_app,
                              _from_entity=_from_entity, **kwds)
```

Comment: Good enough for me! One question, though. Did you mean to call super on Child, not Did?

Comment: This is actually not recommended, see the accepted solution to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279833/how-to-use-a-custom-init-of-an-app-engine-python-model-class-properly

Answer (score 0):

With ndb, you can use a pre put hook method to check if that instance has a parent and raise an exception if it doesnt. I see you are using the older db module, I believe it doesn't have the same hook methods. You should consider moving to the much better and improved ndb datastore API, youll get other benefits like automatic caching and many more.

NDB: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview

NDB model hooks: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks

EDIT: I just reminded that you could do something similar to the ndb model hook with the db API. Explained in [this](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models), great as usual, post from Nick Johnson.

Comment: Yeah ndb is pretty awesome when compared to db. I am using it in other projects. Unfortunately I just don't have the time to spend migrating all of this code right now.

Comment: But, would it be a solution for you to implement something like the hook based solution if you could do it with db?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for the information. This is exactly what I would be looking for if I were using ndb.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed my edit above, but it turns out you can do something like that with db.