# SQLAlchemy: getting a value from the initializer

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following table using **Flask-SQLAlchemy**:

```
class Posts(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hashID = db.Column(db.String(6))
    post = db.Column(db.String(500))

    def __init__(self, post):
        self.hashID = hashid.encode(self.id)
        self.post = post
```

I want to create a hash using the autoincrementd ID field. I saw from other questions `db.session.flush()` can be used however this will not work since I would preferably get the ID from the inside the `init`.

The code above using `self.id` will not work since `self.id` returns a NoneType. Is there a way to get the ID that will be generated from inside the `init`? Thanks.

Comment: You could add `self` to the session then flush but that's not a good idea. Instead of autoincrement you could come up with an ID generation scheme that allows the app to generate the ID instead of the DB.

Comment: @univerio Autoincrement within the app seems to complicated for a possible easier solution.

Comment: I think the problem could be that you are overriding the *\__init\__* method of `db.Model` class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279833/

Comment: And here's the *super* stuff, used to not override class methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222877/.

Comment: @PSidhu You don't have to use an incrementing integer for your ID. You can just as easily generate a UUID for your ID, or a custom ID generation scheme.

Comment: What's the status of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#create-an-instance-of-the-mapped-class) states that the `self.id` attribute is not set until the `INSERT` statement for that entity was issued. That means: unless you don't issue the `INSERT` statement in your `__init__` method you can't get the auto incremented value there.

I don't know the functionality of `hashid.encode` but if that function has no side effects and is fast you won't need to store that field in the database at all. Instead you could add it with a `property`:

```
class Posts(...):
    self.id = ...
    # other columns here

    @property
    def hashID(self):
        return hashid.encode(self.id)
```

Then you only have to make sure that you don't access the `hashID` property before the entity was inserted into the database.

**Note:** this approach does *not* create a column `hashID`. If you need the `hashID` to be a column in the database you can flush the object first and then set the `hashID` like in OP's initial code. For the flushing take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620610/sqlalchemy-obtain-primary-key-with-autoincrement-before-commit).

Comment: It seems dont persistent into DB.

Comment: @RyanChou you are right, the `hashID` is not stored in the DB which is fine in this case as it is only redundant information.

Comment: Yeah. Your answer could satisfy some cases which just only needed read-only. if we want to persist the `hashID`. We would try other ways to generate the Hash value based on the auto-increment ID.