# Custom key for app-engine datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create a simple dictionary on the datastore. So I tried created my Entity class like so

```
class Word(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)
    definition = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Where `id` is the actual word. The thing is when I try to add an entity, I get an error that e.g. “love” is not a key. So I changed to the following

```
class Word(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    definition = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

The problem with this new approach is that my id field isn’t viewed as the actual ID of the Entity. The data store creates my `id`    field plus another `Name/ID` field. How do I use custom ID on App-Engine?

And here is how I’m adding words:

```
word = Word()
word.id = “love”
word.definition =“a profoundly tender, passionate affection for another person. ”
word.put()
```

I am hoping not to have to use [this NamedModel recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465675/custom-keys-for-google-app-engine-models-python) but rather something similar to [this short one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys), except with my structured model class.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other database systems, the key for Datastore is not a user defined column.  The primary key always exists as an explicit item.

From https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/model.html#google.cloud.ndb.model.Model, `entity3 = MyModel(key=ndb.Key(MyModel, "e-three"))`.  It looks like you want

```
class Word(ndb.Model):
  definition = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

new_word = Word(key=ndb.Key(Word, 'love'), definition='a profoundly tender, passionate affection for another person.')
new_word.put()
```

Then a lookup would be `love_record = ndb.Key('Word', 'love').get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with the following

```
with client.context():
  word = Word(
    id = “love”,
    name = "love"
    “a profoundly tender, passionate affection for another person. ”
  )
word.put()
```

After I changed the class to this:

```
class Word(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    definition = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Also I'm using Python3