# Google App Engine unique=True?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I define a unique property for a Model in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185628/how-do-i-define-a-unique-property-for-a-model-in-google-app-engine)

I can't seems to find a way to work the unique property for a model. I followed [How do I define a unique property for a Model in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185628/how-do-i-define-a-unique-property-for-a-model-in-google-app-engine) and a couple other tutorials, but none seems to work?

What's the easiest way to make an unique property?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as "How do I define a unique property for a Model in Gooel App Engine", only it didn't work for you? Without more information about why it didn't work for you, or how yours is different from that question, nobody can help you except for pointing to that question's already-accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to find a different way to do what you want. Google AppEngine does not natively support unique properties, and all of the ways that I have seen to implement them involve either pain or subverting the performance and scalability that are why you should be using it in the first place.